# How to check if any cookies are expired in the cookiecontainer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, cookies, visual-studio-2013

I've got a dependency in my class:

```
    private static CookieContainer _cookieContainer;
```

I would like to iterate through all the cookies, and then if one of them is expired, I would like to run my code to reauthenticate

The pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
foreach(var cookie in _cookieContainer)
{
    if (cookie.IsExpired)
    {
        ReAuthenticate();
        break;
    }
}
```

**How do I iterate over every cookie and check whether it is expired?**

Comment: Where is this code used? In a WinForms/WPF client?

Comment: mvc in visual studio

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the `Cookies` collection from the `Request` object.

```
foreach (HttpCookie thisCookie in this.Request.Cookies)
{
    if (thisCookie.Expires < DateTime.Now)
    {
        // expired
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work in asp.net and here's why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261432/11595253