# Cookie expiry date is always 1/1/0001

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

**Description:**

I'm using cookie in mvc project to remember most recent download format selected by user. While  creating cookie, I'm setting expiry date for that cookie. And when I try to get that cookie and expiry date of that cookie then I'm getting "1/1/0001" as expiry date always. I'm not getting the reason behind this. please help to reason behind this.

**Code:**

1) *Setting cookie and it's expiry date:*

```
 Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(base.LoggedOnUser.Email, exportFileFormat.ToString()));
                    var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[base.LoggedOnUser.Email];
                    if (requestCookie != null)
                    {
                        requestCookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileFormatTypeCookieExpiry"]));
                    }
```

2) *Getting cookie and it's expiry date:*

```
 var fileFormatTypeCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[CurrentUser.Email];
                        if (fileFormatTypeCookie != null && fileFormatTypeCookie.Value != null)
                        {
                            var exportFileFormat = fileFormatTypeCookie.Value;
                            var expiry = fileFormatTypeCookie.Expires;

                        }
```

Above variable expiry is always "1/1/0001".

Comment: If you log the value returned by this line:

DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileFormatTypeCookieExpiry"]))

?

Comment: The logged value is correct expiry date. But when I try to get expiry date from cookie , it is always "1/1/0001"

Comment: [I hope this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441125/why-is-the-cookie-expiration-date-not-surviving-across-sessions-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

I quote the answer from MikeSmithDev from a possible duplicate question:

[Why is the cookie expiration date not surviving across sessions in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441125/why-is-the-cookie-expiration-date-not-surviving-across-sessions-in-asp-net)

> The Short Answer - You cannot read the cookie's expiration date and
>   time.
>
> Slightly Longer Answer - This is not an issue of sessions in ASP.NET.
>   It is an issue of what you can read from a cookie server-side in
>   ASP.NET. Per the MSDN:
>
> The browser is responsible for managing cookies, and the cookie's
>   expiration time and date help the browser manage its store of cookies.
>   Therefore, although you can read the name and value of a cookie, you
>   cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time. When the browser
>   sends cookie information to the server, the browser does not include
>   the expiration information. (The cookie's Expires property always
>   returns a date-time value of zero.)
>
> You can read the Expires property of a cookie that you have set in the
>   HttpResponse object, before the cookie has been sent to the browser.
>   However, you cannot get the expiration back in the HttpRequest object.
>   So basically, the cookie expiration date is set correctly. This can be
>   verified by inspecting the cookie in the browser. Unfortunately,
>   reading this cookie like in your Get function will return 1/1/0001.
>
> If you really want to get the expiration, then you'd have to store it
>   in the cookie itself:

**Set**

```
DateTime exp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1); 
HttpCookie PreferredCookie = new HttpCookie("PreferredCookie"); 
PreferredCookie.Values.Add("cookieType", "Zref"); 
PreferredCookie.Values.Add("exp", exp.ToString());
PreferredCookie.Expires = exp; 
Response.Cookies.Set(PreferredCookie);
```

**Get**

```
HttpCookie PreferredCookie = Request.Cookies["PreferredCookie"];
if (PreferredCookie != null)
{
  CookieLiteral.Text = "Value = " + PreferredCookie["cookieType"] + "<br>";
  CookieLiteral.Text += "Expires = " + PreferredCookie["exp"];
}
else
{
  CookieLiteral.Text = "No Cookie"; 
}
```